# How to run selenium tests using LiveServerTestCase in different browsers?

Tags: python, django, testing, selenium

Need run tests in different browsers successively (i.e. first in firefox, next same tests in chrome..). What is the best way to solve this problem?

Im trying to put loop in setUpClass, but it does not realy helped:

```
class UITest(LiveServerTestCase):

    fixtures = ['initial_test_data.json']

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        for browser in [webdriver.Firefox(), webdriver.PhantomJS(), webdriver.Chrome()]:
            self.selenium = browser
            super(UITest, self).setUpClass()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose I use simple decorator which runs the tests through specified web drivers:

```
import functools


def run_through_drivers(driver_pool='drivers'):
    def wrapped(test_func):
        @functools.wraps(test_func)
        def decorated(test_case, *args, **kwargs):
            test_class = test_case.__class__
            web_driver_pool = getattr(test_class, driver_pool)
            for web_driver in web_driver_pool:
                setattr(test_case, 'selenium', web_driver)
                test_func(test_case, *args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
    return wrapped
```

How to use:

```
class UITest(LiveServerTestCase):

    fixtures = ['initial_test_data.json']
    selenium = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        cls.drivers = WebDriverList(
            webdriver.Chrome(),
            webdriver.Firefox(),
            webdriver.PhantomJS
        )
        super(UITest, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        for driver in cls.drivers:
            driver.quit()
        super(UITest, cls).tearDownClass()

    @run_through_drivers()
    def test_example(self):
        ...
```

Comment: More complete [solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-users/Sckf9y2xIho/mwLTr8YyNDkJ) from Evan Lewis.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution from @Alex Lisovoy appears to be taken from the Evan Lewis solution, which I found didn't work.

I was able to test two browsers at once using the [`nose_parameterized`](https://github.com/wolever/nose-parameterized) module. See my answer/example [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982410/1477364).