# Selenium Python test against Selenium grid created from SeleniumHQ Docker images

Tags: python, testing, docker, selenium-grid

### In brief

How to run Python Selenium tests properly against Selenium Grid container created from SeleniumHQ Docker images?

I also asked on SeleniumHQ here
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/521

### The error & log

- [00 - the console error](https://github.com/namgivu/selenium-docker-sandbox/blob/master/error_note/00.console-error.txt)
- [01 - the hub log](https://github.com/namgivu/selenium-docker-sandbox/blob/master/error_note/01.hub-log.txt)
- [02c - the chrome node log](https://github.com/namgivu/selenium-docker-sandbox/blob/master/error_note/02c.node-log-CH.txt)
- [02f - the firefox node log](https://github.com/namgivu/selenium-docker-sandbox/blob/master/error_note/02f.node-log-FF.txt)

### Full details

I've tried [this web search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=fail+to+execute+selenium+python+test+against+selenium+grid+created+from+SeleniumHQ+docker+images&oq=fail+to+execute+selenium+python+test+against+selenium+grid+created+from+SeleniumHQ+docker+images&aqs=chrome..69i57.90454j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [similar search on our site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Selenium+python+test+against+selenium+grid+created+from+SeleniumHQ+docker+images) and found none useful.

**OK with standalone**

I've succeeded in running [this simple test](https://github.com/namgivu/selenium-docker-sandbox/blob/master/s02a2_tiny_test_standalone.py) against the [standalone selenium grid for Chrome and Firefox](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#standalone-chrome-and-firefox)

- start the grid [view standalone grid create script](https://github.com/namgivu/selenium-docker-sandbox/blob/master/s01b_start_selenium_standalone_grid.sh)

```
docker run -d -p 4445:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome:3.4.0-einsteinium
docker run -d -p 4446:4444 --shm-size 2g selenium/standalone-firefox:3.4.0-einsteinium
```

- run test [view standalone test](https://github.com/namgivu/selenium-docker-sandbox/blob/master/s02a2_tiny_test_standalone.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

SELENIUM_HUB_CH = 'http://localhost:4445/wd/hub' #hub created at file 's01b_start_selenium_standalone_grid.sh'
SELENIUM_HUB_FF = 'http://localhost:4446/wd/hub' #hub created at file 's01b_start_selenium_standalone_grid.sh'

#region webdriver loading
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driverCH = webdriver.Remote(
  command_executor=SELENIUM_HUB_CH,
  desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
)
driverFF = webdriver.Remote(
  command_executor=SELENIUM_HUB_FF,
  desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX,
)
#endregion webdriver loading

for driver in [driverCH, driverFF]:
  driver.get('http://www.google.com')
  print(driver.title)
```

**But FAIL with hub+node grid**

Though I failed to run [that simple test](https://github.com/namgivu/selenium-docker-sandbox/blob/master/s02a1_tiny_test.py) against the [hub+node selenium grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#selenium-grid-hub-and-nodes)

- start the grid [view hub+node creation script](https://github.com/namgivu/selenium-docker-sandbox/blob/master/s01a_start_selenium_grid.sh)

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:3.4.0-einsteinium
docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome:3.4.0-einsteinium
docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox:3.4.0-einsteinium
```

- run the test [view simple test](https://github.com/namgivu/selenium-docker-sandbox/blob/master/s02a1_tiny_test.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

SELENIUM_HUB = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Remote(
  command_executor=SELENIUM_HUB,
  desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
)

driver.get('http://www.google.com')
print(driver.title)
```

**The question**

I am interested in testing against Selenium grid containers i.e. the hub+node container created from [these Docker images](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#selenium-grid-hub-and-nodes).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [lmtierney's answer on github on SeleniumHQ](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/521#issuecomment-315665029)

I can confirm that my test works now after **installing python selenium 3.3.1**

```
pip uninstall selenium ; pip install selenium==3.3.1
```